# Re-writing/Optimising T-SQL Stored Procedure with subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have a stored procedure, now I'm not much of a DBA so I'm just wondering if this is considered bad practise as I have so many subqueries with essentially the same code.

Should I be using table variables or temp tables instead?

Also I have to re-write the second query to be a dynamic SQL as I only want to include the union based on a flag so would a temp table be easier here.

Thanks for all your help

```
CREATE TABLE #Days(theDate datetime, DayAsString varchar(15))

CREATE TABLE #temp(id int identity(1,1),trip_date datetime, trip_return datetime, iteration int, weeknumber int)

IF @SpecificDay = 0
Begin 
    INSERT INTO #Days 
            SELECT [date] ,DATENAME(dw,[date])
                FROM dbo.Calendar C 
                WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @start AND @end
                     AND C.[WkDName] in (select distinct siDay.Name
                                                from schedule s
                                                join ScheduleItemIntervalMap sim on s.schedule_id = sim.scheduleid
                                                join scheduleInterval sint       on sim.scheduleIntervalID = sint.id
                                                left join ScheduleItem siDay     on sim.scheduleDayItemId = siDay.id            
                                                where s.schedule_id = @schedule_id
                                                ) --@wkDName
                     AND C.[Month] in (select distinct siMonth.Id
                                                from schedule s
                                                join ScheduleItemIntervalMap sim on s.schedule_id = sim.scheduleid
                                                join scheduleInterval sint       on sim.scheduleIntervalID = sint.id                                
                                                join ScheduleItem siMonth        on sim.ScheduleMonthItemId = siMonth.id
                                                where s.schedule_id =  @schedule_id
                                                ) --@Month
                     AND C.[WkNo] in (select distinct sint.Id
                                                from schedule s
                                                join ScheduleItemIntervalMap sim on s.schedule_id = sim.scheduleid
                                                join scheduleInterval sint       on sim.scheduleIntervalID = sint.id                                
                                                join ScheduleItem siDay        on sim.ScheduleDayItemId = siDay.Id
                                                where s.schedule_id =  @schedule_id)          --@first last etc @occurence
                Union all --include the last occurence of the month
                SELECT [date] ,DATENAME(dw,[date])
                FROM dbo.Calendar CLast
                WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @start AND @end
                     AND CLast.[WkDName] in (select distinct siDay.Name
                                                from schedule s
                                                join ScheduleItemIntervalMap sim on s.schedule_id = sim.scheduleid
                                                join scheduleInterval sint       on sim.scheduleIntervalID = sint.id
                                                left join ScheduleItem siDay     on sim.scheduleDayItemId = siDay.id            
                                                where s.schedule_id =  @schedule_id
                                                ) --@wkDName
                     AND CLast.[Month] in (select distinct siMonth.Id
                                                from schedule s
                                                join ScheduleItemIntervalMap sim on s.schedule_id = sim.scheduleid
                                                join scheduleInterval sint       on sim.scheduleIntervalID = sint.id                                
                                                join ScheduleItem siMonth        on sim.ScheduleMonthItemId = siMonth.id
                                                where s.schedule_id =  @schedule_id
                                                ) --@Month
                     AND CLast.[Last] = 1
    END 
ELSE --Specific date has been specified or last has been selected
    INSERT INTO #Days 
    select distinct [date] ,DATENAME(dw,[date]) from 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Calendar C 
        WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @start AND @end
             AND C.[Month] in (select distinct siMonth.Id
                                        from schedule s
                                        join ScheduleItemIntervalMap sim on s.schedule_id = sim.scheduleid
                                        join scheduleInterval sint       on sim.scheduleIntervalID = sint.id                                
                                        join ScheduleItem siMonth        on sim.ScheduleMonthItemId = siMonth.id
                                        where s.schedule_id = @schedule_id) --@Month
             AND C.[Day] in (select distinct sint.Name
                                        from schedule s
                                        join ScheduleItemIntervalMap sim on s.schedule_id = sim.scheduleid
                                        join scheduleInterval sint       on sim.scheduleIntervalID = sint.id                                
                                        join ScheduleItem siMonth        on sim.ScheduleMonthItemId = siMonth.id
                                        where s.schedule_id = @schedule_id
                                        AND sint.Name <> 'Last'
             )
        Union all --include the last occurence of the month IF LAST
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Calendar CLast
        WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @start AND @end
             AND CLast.[Month] in (select distinct siMonth.Id
                                        from schedule s
                                        join ScheduleItemIntervalMap sim on s.schedule_id = sim.scheduleid
                                        join scheduleInterval sint       on sim.scheduleIntervalID = sint.id                                
                                        join ScheduleItem siMonth        on sim.ScheduleMonthItemId = siMonth.id
                                        where s.schedule_id = @schedule_id
                                        ) --@Month
                                        AND [Date] in (select LDtOfMo from dbo.Calendar 
                                                        WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @start AND @end)
            ) as x


Begin 
        INSERT INTO #temp(trip_date,trip_return,iteration,weeknumber)
        SELECT 
            theDate + CAST(@timeout AS DATETIME),theDate+ CAST(@timeback AS DATETIME),@WeekNo,DATEPART(wk, theDate+CAST(@timeout AS DATETIME))
        FROM
            #Days           
        END
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to use correlated EXISTS subqueries rather than IN subqueries.  You might try that method to see of you get different, and more optimal, execution plans.  In many cases, the optimizer is smart enough to generate the best plan for queries that are semantically identical.

Comment: In addition to what @Dan said, at the very least, take out the `DISTINCT`...

Comment: Cheers @dan, I will try with EXISTS. I presume EXISTS moves on once an occurence is found as opposed to IN returning all results?

Comment: @Aaron I thought using distinc would would improve the performance due to only one result, or does it create more overhead? should i leave it up to the analyzer to remove duplicates?

Comment: It has to sort to eliminate duplicates - chances are adding that sorting work costs more than just returning the rows in whatever efficient sort order inherent in the rest of the query - especially since those rows aren't actually materialized.

Comment: @user2329438, you are correct that EXISTS need only check for existence.  But even with IN, the optimizer might be smart enough to do that too because the semantics are the same here.  Keep in mind that SQL is declarative rather than procedural.  SQL Server may optimize the query regardless of how you express the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing the same `JOIN` repeatedly; you can probably convert those subqueries in a `JOIN` like below

```
INSERT INTO #Days 
        SELECT DISTINCT C.[date] ,DATENAME(dw,C.[date])
            FROM dbo.Calendar C 
            left join ScheduleItem si
            ON si.Name = C.[WkDName]
            AND si.Id = C.[Month]
            JOIN ScheduleItemIntervalMap sim ON sim.scheduleDayItemId = si.id
            JOIN schedule s ON s.schedule_id = sim.scheduleid
            JOIN scheduleInterval sint on sim.scheduleIntervalID = sint.id
            AND sint.Id = C.[WkNo]
            where s.schedule_id = @schedule_id
            AND C.[Date] BETWEEN @start AND @end
```